# Converting multiple dropdowns to divs and grouping them jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to convert select dropdowns into divs, im pretty close to achieving that but the problem is the div are not separated into group like the dropdowns are. In my results I was able to convert them but it put all of my option under the ul and didn't seperate them.

```js
  var $select = $('#miopts2 select'),
            $ul = $('<ul></ul>').attr('id', $select.attr('id')).attr('name', $select.attr('name'));
    
    
        $select.children().each(function(e, i) {
            var $options = $(this);
            $('<li></li>').val($options.val()).text($options.text()).appendTo($ul);
        });
    
        $select.replaceWith($ul);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="miopts2" class="border-right-0 border-left-0 my-3">
                        <select name="5:finopt:0" size="1">
                            <option value="Processors;n" selected="">Processors</option>
                            <option value="3.8 GHz;+45.00;">3.8 GHz</option>
                            <option value="4.2 GHz;+45.00;">4.2 GHz</option>
                        </select>
                        <select name="5:finopt:1" size="1">
                            <option value="Memory" selected="">Memory</option>
                            <option value="8GB;+20.00;">8GB</option>
                            <option value="16GB;+20.00;">16GB</option>
                            <option value="32GB;+20.00;">32GB</option>
                            <option value="64GB;+20.00;">64GB</option>
                        </select>
                        <select name="5:finopt:2" size="1">
                            <option value="Storage" selected="">Storage</option>
                            <option value="2TB;+100.00;">2TB</option>
                            <option value="3TB;+100.00;">3TB</option>
                            <option value="512GB SSD;+100.00;">512GB SSD</option>
                            <option value="1TB SSD;+100.00;">1TB SSD</option>
                            <option value="2TB SSD;+100.00;">2TB SSD</option>
                        </select>
                        <select name="5:finopt:3" size="1">
                            <option value="Mouse or Trackpad" selected="">Mouse or Trackpad</option>
                            <option value="Magic Mouse">Magic Mouse</option>
                            <option value="Magic Trackpad">Magic Trackpad</option>
                            <option value="Mouse + Trackpad;+400.00;">Mouse + Trackpad</option>
                        </select>
                        <input type="hidden" name="5:finoptnum" value="4">
                    </div>

These are my Current results.

    <ul name="5:finopt:0">
    <li value="0">Processors</li>
    <li value="0">3.8 GHz</li>
    <li value="0">4.2 GHz</li>
    <li value="0">Memory</li>
    <li value="0">8GB</li>
    <li value="0">16GB</li>
    <li value="0">32GB</li>
    <li value="0">64GB</li>
    <li value="0">Storage</li>
    <li value="0">2TB</li>
    <li value="0">3TB</li>
    <li value="0">512GB SSD</li>
    <li value="0">1TB SSD</li>
    <li value="0">2TB SSD</li>
    <li value="0">Mouse or Trackpad</li>
    <li value="0">Magic Mouse</li>
    <li value="0">Magic Trackpad</li>
    <li value="0">Mouse + Trackpad</li>
    </ul>

This is what I am trying to achieve.

    <ul name="5:finopt:0">
    <li value="0">Processors</li>
    <li value="0">3.8 GHz</li>
    <li value="0">4.2 GHz</li>
    </ul>
    
    <ul name="5:finopt:1">
    <li value="0">Memory</li>
    <li value="0">8GB</li>
    <li value="0">16GB</li>
    <li value="0">32GB</li>
    <li value="0">64GB</li>
    </ul>
    
    <ul name="5:finopt:2">
    <li value="0">Storage</li>
    <li value="0">2TB</li>
    <li value="0">3TB</li>
    <li value="0">512GB SSD</li>
    <li value="0">1TB SSD</li>
    <li value="0">2TB SSD</li>
    </ul>
    
    <ul name="5:finopt:3">
    <li value="0">Mouse or Trackpad</li>
    <li value="0">Magic Mouse</li>
    <li value="0">Magic Trackpad</li>
    <li value="0">Mouse + Trackpad</li>
    </ul>
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your code as below.

```
$('#miopts2 select').each(function() {
    var $select = $(this);
    var $ul = $('<ul></ul>').attr('id', $select.attr('id')).attr('name', $select.attr('name'));

    $select.children().each(function(e, i) {
        var $options = $(this);
        $('<li></li>').val($options.val()).text($options.text()).appendTo($ul);
    });

    $select.replaceWith($ul);
});
```

Your complete code will be as below.

```js
$('#miopts2 select').each(function() {
  var $select = $(this);
  var $ul = $('<ul></ul>').attr('id', $select.attr('id')).attr('name', $select.attr('name'));

  $select.children().each(function(e, i) {
    var $options = $(this);
    $('<li></li>').val($options.val()).text($options.text()).appendTo($ul);
  });

  $select.replaceWith($ul);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="miopts2" class="border-right-0 border-left-0 my-3">
  <select name="5:finopt:0" size="1">
    <option value="Processors;n" selected="">Processors</option>
    <option value="3.8 GHz;+45.00;">3.8 GHz</option>
    <option value="4.2 GHz;+45.00;">4.2 GHz</option>
  </select>
  <select name="5:finopt:1" size="1">
    <option value="Memory" selected="">Memory</option>
    <option value="8GB;+20.00;">8GB</option>
    <option value="16GB;+20.00;">16GB</option>
    <option value="32GB;+20.00;">32GB</option>
    <option value="64GB;+20.00;">64GB</option>
  </select>
  <select name="5:finopt:2" size="1">
    <option value="Storage" selected="">Storage</option>
    <option value="2TB;+100.00;">2TB</option>
    <option value="3TB;+100.00;">3TB</option>
    <option value="512GB SSD;+100.00;">512GB SSD</option>
    <option value="1TB SSD;+100.00;">1TB SSD</option>
    <option value="2TB SSD;+100.00;">2TB SSD</option>
  </select>
  <select name="5:finopt:3" size="1">
    <option value="Mouse or Trackpad" selected="">Mouse or Trackpad</option>
    <option value="Magic Mouse">Magic Mouse</option>
    <option value="Magic Trackpad">Magic Trackpad</option>
    <option value="Mouse + Trackpad;+400.00;">Mouse + Trackpad</option>
  </select>
  <input type="hidden" name="5:finoptnum" value="4">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you try iterating over the select, rather than on the options. 
the $select.childrens().each is iterating over all the options. So you will need to iterate over select or you will need to identify the parent in the current loop.

```
$select.each(function(e,i){
 $ul = $('<ul></ul>').attr('id', $(this).attr('id')).attr('name', $(this).attr('name'));
 $(this).find('option').each(function(e,i){
 var $options = $(this);
    $('<li></li>').val($options.val()).text($options.text()).appendTo($ul);
 })
 //make use of this $ul
 })
```